# \footcite in Beamer

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I'm using `biblatex` and its `\footcite` command within `beamer` and when I want to reference two references together like `\footcite{ref1,ref2}`, I get a single number with two contiguous references as footnote?

my `biblatex` code is as follows and i am not sure waht is wrong:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote,maxnames=10,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I think you should use `\footcites{key1}{key2}`, or `\mfootcite{key1,key2}` with the `mcite` package option. In any case, you'll get a simple marker in the text (it's a single footnote, after all), and a semicolon separated list of the references associated to `key1`, `key2` in the footnote text.

Comment: yes I understand this is a single footnote but these are still two different references. I was expecting a result similar to `\cite{key1,key2}`

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow-witted, but I don't get *what* result you are expecting. Could you add a detailed description?

Comment: I would expect to superscripts with two distinct footnotes. does it make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to refer the documentation of biblatex:

> `\footcite[ prenote ][ postnote ]{ key }`
>
> `\footcitetext[ prenote ][ postnote ]{ key }`
>
> These command use a format similar to `\cite` but
>   put the entire citation in a footnote and add a period at the end. In
>   the footnote, they automatically capitalize the name prefix of the
>   first name if the `useprefix` option is enabled, provided that there
>   is a name prefix and the citation style prints any name at all.
>   `\footcitetext` differs from `\footcite` in that it uses
>   `\footnotetext` instead of `\footnote`.

You can see that this behavior is independently from `beamer`.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote,maxnames=10,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backend=biber,mcite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{ctan,companion}

Test\footcites{ctan}{companion}

Test\mfootcite{ctan,companion}

Test\footcite{ctan}\footcite{companion}
\end{document}
```

You can create you own command. My first idea is very simple:

```
\newrobustcmd*\footcitesep[1]{%
   \forcsvlist{\footcite}{#1}%
}
```